# Need help identifying this part please

Tags: voltage

[image]  This is on a control board from a crane...not sure of crane mfg or country of origin. Anyway, owner lost 12Vdc to the board and tried to jumper it in...ooops.  This is where the smoke came out...can't seem to find anything on this part.  Another part next door is also designated V but unfortunately it's not the same and I can't find that either. Letters appear to read GP447.  Thanks all!

Comment: Can you add an image of the board/part?

Comment: Isn't the GP marking just an acronym for General Purpose (rectifier)?

Comment: Maybe a unidirectional transzorb (TVS) which may or may not have given its life to save other parts. If it's directly across the "12V" input (+ on the left, - on the right), you can try replacing it with one rated to accept the input voltage.

Answer (score 3):

That's some kind of diode, possibly in a SMA package.  Note the cathode band on the left end (as oriented in your picture).

The designation "V" hints that it might be used as a voltage reference, which would mean a Zener diode.  However, without seeing the rest of the circuit or a repair manual, there is no way to know.

If there is another diode on the board with the same markings, you can unsolder it and find its voltage.

However, it is quite possible that other parts on this board are damaged too, just not showing it in a obvious way.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it it is a ST part. Problem is, the actual product marking is right where the case blew up. So there is no way to determine the correct part based on the code.

Here is the typical marking of a ST diode in a SMx case:

[image: typical marking of a ST diode]

You can guesstimate the ST logo, the e3 marking is there and there is a three digit code in the bottom right corner. Not sure if the manufacturing location was upped to a two letter code at some point or for other products.

There are a lot of ST diodes and I'm not going through every datasheet to find out.

My guess could be way off of course.